# my banner images do not change banner in speed and dalay that I set in jQuery script

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slider, unslider

Im using unslider for a slidershow with many images.

I already have plugin working fine, but, I can´t understand why, Im delay, and speed options dont work correctly.

I want my banner images to change in each  7 seconds, and I want a delay of 3 seconds. So I set my speed at 7000 (milliseconds) and delay with 3000. But dont works. I dont get speed and delay that I set in jQuery script.

Somebody there can give me a help trying to understand what is happening here?

I have this fiddle with my example: http://jsfiddle.net/bdmU4/3/

Below, there is my jQuery to start unslider plugin:

```
$(function (){  
$('.banner').unslider({
    speed: 3000,               //  The speed to animate each slide (in milliseconds)
    delay: 7000,              //  The delay between slide animations (in milliseconds)
    complete: function() {},  //  A function that gets called after every slide animation
    keys: true,               //  Enable keyboard (left, right) arrow shortcuts
    dots: true,               //  Display dot navigation
    fluid: false              //  Support responsive design. May break non-responsive designs
});
```

And here I have my html:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://unslider.com/unslider.min.js"></script>
<section id="banner-container"> 
    <div class="banner">
        <ul>          
            <li style="background-color:blue; height:200px; "></li>
             <li style="background-color:red; height:200px; "></li>
            <li style="background-color:yellow; height:200px; "></li>
            <li style="background-color:green; height:200px; "></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<a href="#" class="unslider-arrow prev">Previous Slide</a>
<a href="#" class="unslider-arrow next">Next slide</a>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing around with your fiddle (I reduced it to the core example on their site), it looks like the `speed` is not subtracted from the `delay`.

If you want 3 seconds to transition plus 7 full seconds of display, then I would change your `delay` to `10000`.

Additionally, in your fiddle, you are declaring the slider twice so that might have weird effects. `var unslider = $('.banner').unslider();` is the second occurrence.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Steve Tauber. But I use this second declaration "var unslider = $('.banner').unslider();" to change slides by clicking on arrows. Do you know how can I mantain this code without declaring slider twice?

Comment: Yeah, just declare it once then use the variable. Here's an example for jQueryUI dialog: `var myDiag = jQuery('#dialog').dialog();` THEN if you want to open it: `myDiag.dialog('open');`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Steve Tauber. But like that, How can I set speed and delay that I want? Because Im here trying to set options and its not working...

Comment: Your initial declaration returns an `unslider` object. Just store it when you make the original declaration. Remove the second declaration and then reference the variable from the first declaration.

Comment: Steve Tauber thanks for your help, I have this fiddle now: http://jsfiddle.net/bdmU4/6/. And my arrows links dont work on internet explorer. Do you have idea why this ca be happening?

Comment: I would rename the variable to something other than "unslider" since the library uses the same... maybe `myUnslider`. And then I would wrap all the javascript inside a jQuery document ready block: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Thanks for your answer Steve Tauber. But even with your tips...dont works in internet explorer :SS

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the necropost,
I had the same issue, no matter what speed/delay I put in, it would not effect it.

Also if I changed slides using the "dots", the slides would jump back to where it started from and all the timing would be thrown out.

All I did was remove the line:

```
var unslider = $('.banner').unslider();
```

As Steve pointed out.
I think calling a second occurrence of the script overwrites things and it gets confused which speeds to follow, as essentially theres 2 running at the same time.

I reply here in the hopes it will aid someone in the future.